# Using the decorator pattern with slickgrid and messaging between decorators

Tags: javascript, decorator, slickgrid

I am trying to implement slickgrid using a decorator design pattern. I start with a coregrid that contains the slickgrid object and has all the "public" functions that all the other decorators will implement. To illustrate I will give you an example. coregrid is passed to and wrapped by the AddRecordDecorator that adds the add record functionality to the grid. The grid is then passed to and wrapped by the FilterDecorator that adds the filter functionality. That grid is then passed to and wrapped by the FindAndReplaceDecorator that adds the find and replace functionality and is the final wrapper. This all happens in the GridFactory and looks something like this.

```
function getMyGrid(type,htmlId,tableMetaData){
var grid = getCoreGrid(type,htmlId,tableMetaData);  
    grid = new AddRecordDecorator(grid);
    grid = new FilterDecorator(grid);
    grid = new FindAndReplaceDecorator(grid);   
    return grid;
    }
```

This is working great because now I can use the GridFactory to make grids of different types that have only the functionality I need them to have and I can have multiple grids on one page because they all have an unique id.

Now I want some of the decorators to communicate with each other.

The problem is that none of the decorators know about each other and cannot invoke methods for the other decorators. The FilterDecorator does not know about the AddRecordDecorator so if you have the grid filtered and then you add a record to that grid the data does not get refiltered. Because the FilterDecorator is unaware an add event happened. So somehow I need these two to talk to each other.

I was considering having a messaging queue class that any of the decorators can write to and any of the decorators can listen to. That way when AddRecord makes a change it can tell whichever decorators that are listening to the messaging queue that a change has been made.

My other option was to have decorators register in the coregrid and coregrid knows what decorators have been added and can send calls to those functions directly.

I am questioning if these options break the decorator design pattern and if so is there another way to implement this? I would like to adhere to the pattern but this is my first time using it and I don't want to create a hack that will cause problems down the line.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would probably extend upon the concepts already used within the framework. You could use some of the available events or define custom events and subscribe to them within the decorators.

Comment: I used this event but I am worried that it is too far reaching. I am concerned that on some CellChange it may not be appropriate to re-filter. `grid.coreGrid.slickgrid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
       filterGrid();
     });`